# Spying on a wired service in angular karma test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Is it possible to spy on a service in a karma test that was wired by Angular?

Example: `myService` is the unit under test. `thirdParty` stands for a third party service that should be spied on.

```
.service('thirdParty', function() {
    return {
        hello: function() {
            return 'hello world';
        }
    }
})
.service('myService', function(thirdParty) {
    return {
        world: function() {
            return thirdParty.hello();
        }
    }
})
```

In my karma test I would like to spy on `thirdParty` service and call the real service:

```
describe('spy', function() {
    var thirdParty, myService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_thirdParty_, _myService_) {
        myService = _myService_;
        thirdParty = _thirdParty_;

        spyOn(thirdParty, 'hello').andCallThrough();
    }));

    it('should be called in myService', function() {
        expect(thirdParty.hello).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(myService.world()).toBe('hello world');
    });
})
```

The point is that my test should assert that

1. a specific method of the third party service has been called inside `myService`
2. the third party service doesn't change its internal behaviour that would lead to a an exception or unexpected result (e.g. after a library update)

The `myService.world()` assertion just works but as I expect `myService` doesn't operate on the spied `thirdParty` service.

The result is:

```
Expected spy hello to have been called.
```

In some tests I'm already mocking third party services with a `provider` and a bare mock. 
So I tried to create a spying instance of `cacheFactory` that comes with [`angular-cache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cache):

```
beforeEach(module('angular-cache'));

beforeEach(module(function($provide, $injector, CacheFactoryProvider) {
    //CacheFactoryProvider requires $q service
    var q = $injector.get('$q');
    var cacheFactory = CacheFactoryProvider.$get[1](q);

    spyOn(cacheFactory, 'createCache').andCallThrough();
    $provide.factory('CacheFactory', cacheFactory);
}));
```

Now I`m facing the chicken-and-egg problem:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function ($provide, $injector, CacheFactoryProvider) due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $q
```

I know that this example can't work but because of lack of knowledge of the internals how Angular is actually instantiating and wiring services I would like to ask the community whether my test approach is possible or even sane. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
it('should be called in myService', function() {
    expect(thirdParty.hello).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(myService.world()).toBe('hello world');
});
```

the test should be

```
it('should be called in myService', function() {
    expect(myService.world()).toBe('hello world');
    expect(thirdParty.hello).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Indeed, the `thirdParty.hello` method won't have been called until you actually call `myService.world()`.

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much. I don't know why I haven't though about it.